# Amazon Pay Integration with React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, amazon-pay

Do anyone know any library or SDK to integrate Amazon-Pay with mobile app using React Native?

I have tried this following example from medium but I think it is for ReactJS only.

https://medium.com/@avremelk/amazonpay-react-js-f2c84931f82b